# Second order ODE solution verification

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Knowing that $x'(-3) = 1$ and $x(-3)=0$ solve
$$
3x'x'' = e^x
$$
I start with letting $u(x)=x'$. Plugging that in into the equation leaves me with:
$$
u u' = \frac{e^x}{3u}
$$
$$
3u^2 du = e^x dx
$$
integrate that to get
$$
(x')^3 = u^3 = e^x + c
$$
I suppose I should use here the fact that $x'(-3) = 1$ and $x(-3) = 0$:
$$
1^3 = e^{x(-3)} + c \\
1 = 1 + c \implies c = 0
$$ 
so 
$$
(\frac{dx}{dt})^3 = e^x\\
\frac{dt}{dx} = e^{-\frac{x}{3}}\\
dt = e^{-\frac{x}{3}}dx\\
t = -3e^{-\frac{x}{3}} + c
$$
Plug in $x(-3) = 0$ again:
$$
-3 = -3e^0 + c \implies c = 0
$$
So the final solution is 
$$
t = -3e^{-\frac{x}{3}} 
$$
which can be modified to:
$$
(-\frac{1}{3}t)^{-3} = e^x\\
x(t) = -3\ln(-\frac{1}{3}t)
$$
Is that a correct solution?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. You could shorten the first lines by directly multiplying the original equation with $x'$ and then integrating.